# looking for RexEx to replace a string within a string

Tags: regex, string, powershell, parsing, text

I have to replace a string in a text file with Powershell. The text file has this content:

```
app.framework.locale=de_DE
app.gf.data.profile=somevalues,somevalues[,...]
app.gf.data.profile.path=C:\somepath\somesubpath
app.basket.currencies=currencies
```

I want to set the profile and the profile.path. So everything behind the "=" should be replaced, regardless of how long the string behind the "=" is.

I am reading the file, replacing the string, and writing back the file with these commands:

change the profile:

```
(Get-Content $TXT_FILE ).Replace('app.gf.data.profile=default,',"app.gf.data.profile=default,$Man") | Out-File $TXT_FILE -Encoding ASCII
```

change the profile path:

```
(Get-Content $TXT_FILE ).Replace('app.gf.data.profile.path=',"app.gf.data.profile.path=$Path") | Out-File $TXT_FILE -Encoding ASCII
```

As you can see, my replacement script is not correct, the rest behind the "=" will remain. I think I need a regex or some kind of wildcards to fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
(Get-Content $TXT_FILE) `
  -replace '^(app\.gf\.data\.profile=).*', "`$1,$Man" `
  -replace '^(app\.gf\.data\.profile\.path=).*', "`${1}$Path" | `
Out-File $TXT_FILE -Encoding ASCII
```

Here, `-replace` is used to enable regex replacing, and both regular expressions follow a similar logic:

- `^` - matches start of a line
- `(app\.gf\.data\.profile=)` - captures a literal string (literal dots in regex must be escaped) into Group 1 (`$1` or `${1}`)
- `.*` - matches the rest of the line.

`${1}` is used in the second case as the variable `$Path` follows the backreference immediately, and if it starts with a digit, the replacement will not be as expected.